# Parsing SOAP result using TouchXML in iOS SDK (iPad)

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, soap, touchxml

I'm working on an iPad project that is using functions in a WebService.
Handling webservice connection, data etc works find. But i'm not able to parse the result SOAP using TouchXML. Getting the nodes out of the xml always returns 0 length.

The output xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <soap:Body>
        <LogOnResponse xmlns="http://coreservices.org/v1">
            <LogOnResult>
                <Id>1c0e9ad0-a3be-4cd0-8f0d-0616a63a4e28</Id>
                <userId>2</userId>
                <user>
                    <ID>2
                    <Name>Beheerder
                    <emailAddress />
                    <cultureName>nl-NL</cultureName>
                </user>
            </LogOnResult>
        </LogOnResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

parser code:

```
 NSData *aData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:[webData mutableBytes]
                                        length:[webData length]];

 NSString *xmlData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:aData 
                                           encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

 NSLog(@"%@", xmlData);

 [xmlData release];

 CXMLDocument *domUserIdentity = [[[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:aData 
                                                             options:0 
                                                               error:nil]
                                                                autorelease];
 [aData release];

 NSArray *nodesList = [domUserIdentity nodesForXPath:@"//LogOnResult" error:nil]; // 0 length

    for (CXMLElement *resultElement in nodesList) {
        for (int counter = 0; counter 
            NSString *elemName = [[resultElement childAtIndex:counter] name];
            NSString * elemValue = [[[resultElement childAtIndex:counter]
                                                             stringValue] 
                                        stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                        [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

   [elemName release];
   [elemValue release];
  }
}

 [nodesList release];
```

Any idea what did i do wrong?

Thank's alot in advance.

Inoel

Answer (score 1):

Try using the NSXMLDocument, it should work as well as CXMLDocument. Here are some docs:
[link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSXML_Concepts/Articles/CreatingXMLDoc.html)

Comment: NSXMLDocument is a cocoa specific thing right? i don't think i can use this with iOS SDK. I can't find any library nor framework to use this.

Comment: I realize it's late, but the KissXML library (http://code.google.com/p/kissxml/) duplicates the NSXMLDocument classes in iOS (plus adds some features).  I'm not associated with the library, but find it very helpful in lots of my own code!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using an XPath Parser. You aren't doing anything too heavy, so the speed hit is *well* worth it. My personal choice is [TFHpple](http://github.com/topfunky/hpple). There are slightly faster and more precise solutions out there, but I find TFHpple's simplicity hard to beat.

**Example:**

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"example.html"]; 

// Create parser
xpathParser = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithXMLData:data];

NSArray *elements = [xpathParser search:@"//LogOnResult"];

TFHppleElement *element = [elements objectAtIndex:0];

// Get the text within the cell tag
NSString *content = [element content];

[xpathParser release];
[data release];
```

Obviously you'd have to write some code to save the parts you want. Looking at this data, I'd probably make a custom data holder class that you can access with properties. You can parse your XML into that and then save it as a property in the view controller that will be accessing it.

Happy coding!

Comment: TFHpple? is this new kind of xml parser? how reliable is this? That's what i'm trying todo with TouchXML. xpath, but it doesn't give the result i wanted. :(

Comment: TouchXML is a pain in the ass to set up. That's why I use TFHpple. It uses the same Xpath expressions, but it's much easier to get setup. The readme on the GitHub page is literally all you'll ever need.